# Is this possible in JQUERY? val() and text()

Tags: jquery

Is this possible in one liner code in JQUERY?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- Ex. this is the td:nth-child(10) -->
    <td> 
      <input type="hidden" value=""/> 
      <p> </p> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

// I'd like to ouput a same value in td 10th cell in one liner code..
$(this).children('td:nth-child(10)').text(data[0]).val(date[0]);
```

Any Help Thanks?

Comment: `val()` is not required as `td` element doesn't have `value` property.

Comment: yes it is but both have different meaning 
.val() is for the HTML attribute "value"

.text() is for the innerHTML (similar to .html() )

Comment: Try this..`$(this).children('td:nth-child(10)').text(data[0]).end().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(date[0]);`

Comment: Thank You I have already run it using your code, but the problem now is, when i changed the value in td 10th cell the input field was disappeared. How I will debug this?

Answer (score 1):

**OLD ANSWER:**
Yes, you can. But it won't make any sense since `td` doesn't use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. When the first element in the
>   collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a select element with the
>   multiple attribute set), it returns an array containing the value of
>   each selected option, or null if no options are selected. When called
>   on an empty collection, it returns undefined.

Below is a snippet where `text()` is used first, and then `val()`. But `val()` doesnt affect anything.

**Update**: With the new HTML, you can set the `P` and then the `input`.

```js
changeIt = function(){
  $('td:nth-child(2) p').text('foo').closest('td').find('input').val('bar');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="inital1"/>
      <p>1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="inital2"/>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="inital3"/>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="inital4"/>
      <p>4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="changeIt()">Click two change 2</button>
```

Comment: Questioned changed while I was typing... Didn't see the hidden input. Will change answer.

Comment: hi thank you, is this hidden input will not disappeared after the button is going to click? thanks

Comment: No, the input will not disappear after click, since you're setting `text` on the `p` instead of resetting the entire `td`.

Comment: Hi it was really disappeared and I didn't know why anyways I've already did it using `find('p')` before `text()`. Thanks for your code Sir! Have a nice day. :)